# Api Null if statementt

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my js code:
When the API is being used (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/) and I take a currency example: lisk, it gives for the  "max_supply": null, . I want "null" to be displayed as "none".

This is my JS code:

```
  $("#max_supply").html(data[i].max_supply) {
      if ((data[i].max_supply) == null) {
          (("#max_supply") = "none");
      }
  }
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Exactly what do you think `("#max_supply") = "none";` is doing? Because it's not what you think it is.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Ye I know, instead on "none" i put a infinite sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is what you're looking for:**

*Using a Conditional (ternary) Operator*

```
$("#max_supply").html(data[i].max_supply == null ? 'none' : data[i].max_supply);
```